# Pipe does not run when the data update

Tags: typescript, angular

I want when one of users changes his name, let the user list update the name automatically.

When I use `{{user.profile.name}}`, it works well. However, when I use `UserNamePipe`, it does not work.

I also made a small example (including async pipe way too) to test, but this example runs well. http://plnkr.co/edit/RtxMgDBd3lLeUHU2M3n6?p=preview

So what can be my problem? Thanks

**// app.ts**

```ts
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserNamePipe} from './user-name.pipe';
@View({
    pipes: [UserNamePipe],
    template: `
        <div class="row">
            <a *ngFor="#user of users">
                {{user.profile.name}}  <!--this changes automatically when the other use change his name-->
                {{user|userName}}  <!--this has problem which won't update automatically-->
            </a>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    users:any;
    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.users = getFromDatabase();
    }
}
```

**// user-name.pipe.ts**

```ts
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'userName'
})
export class UserNamePipe {
    transform(user:any):string {
        console.log("UserNamePipe runs"); // This actually didn't run when the other user changes his name
        return user.profile.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```ts
{{user.profile.name}}
```

Angular checks whether the `.name` has changed where

```ts
{{user|userName}}
```

is only evaluated when `user` changed.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know where the problem is. Is there a smart way to solve this?

Comment: I haven't played much with pipes myself yet. You could try to set `pure: false` in the `@Pipe()` decorator.

Comment: oh, yeah, that is one way

Comment: I updated my question, waiting whether there is a async solution.

Comment: I don't understand the updated question. What's the problem with the current approach?

Comment: Oh, because showing 10 users, before UserNamePipe only runs 10 times. After using pure: false, it runs thousands of times..

Comment: I see. yes that's the effect of `pure`. It is checked every time any event occures, related to users or not.

Comment: To make my question clear, I already simplified my pipe codes in the question. My real several pipes actually query from the database. I don’t want them keep querying from the database. So that is why I want a async way. :P

Comment: Can you pleaes make this more obvious in your question?

Comment: What does the pipe actually get from database? Can't you just cache the value and only access the database if something changed?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I probably create another question about async, because this seems like another one. thanks a lot!!